# How to save web proxy enabled logs of mikrotik into remote mysql database

Tags: logging, syslog, webproxy

Currently I am developing a web application that works with freeradius. Some days before client asked me to develop a module to save users activity logs into remote database. I tried syslog-ng. I successfully saved its logs into database, but it only saves users login and logout activity and some admin activities. My client need to store users visited URL's data and source IP's logs into database. I search on google for 4 days but all in vain. I tried web proxy technique but it shows me logs in winbox window. I can't transfer these logs into remote mysql database. I found an windows based software that accepts logs of proxy server but I am using Linux based server. I need to capture Web proxy enabled logs in remote server and then save these logs into database.

My software is hosting on a server machine having ubuntu 14.4 installed on it.
One thing more that my client is not in position to purchase any third party software.

My English is not good so plz try to understand what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your web server's logs. It will be your Apache (or nginx) logs that have that information.